# Navigation bar gone but categories still there

Tags: magento

I'm having some trouble, with Magneto.
The theme is "Modern Theme"

Can't post pictures, but the image of the navigation + buttons are gone.
Theres like little links floating around: home, contact etc

Instead of them being in the navigation bar in a row next to each other.
The navigation bar is gone and theres a row of vertical categorys.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What have you tried to fix it?  Have you cleared the cache or rebuilt indexes (from the System menu in admin)?  From your description it sounds like some CSS is not being loaded.  In your browser press F12, click on the "Network" tab and reload the page to see what is and is not loaded.  Note any problems you spot and post them here.

Comment: I've tried everything i could think of. To bad i can't show image.

Comment: But the whole navigation bar is gone, only thing that remains are the categorys. The whole design is gone, only thing that remains are linked words.

Comment: One thing i suddenly remember is that the navigation dissapears from the default, blank and morden theme. i also have the absolute theme and that one works.

Comment: If the problem started when you installed absolute theme then uninstall it and see if that helps.